# Python url does not download file

Tags: python, urllib2

I am developing a quant trading app which sources financial information from yahoo finance. The code is given below.

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import timegm
import time

def constructYFURL(ticker, start_date,end_date,freq):
    start_date = str(timegm(time.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
    end_date = str(timegm(time.strptime(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d")))
    if freq == 'w':
        interval = '1wk'
    else:
        interval = '1mo'
    if freq == 'd':
        interval = '1d'
    yFURL = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/"+ticker+"?      period1="+start_date+"&period2="+end_date+"&interval="+interval+"&events=history&crumb=jfsRogYbS3."
    return yFURL


def download(filePath, urlOfFile):
    import urllib2

    webRequest = urllib2.Request(urlOfFile)

    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(webRequest)
        content = page.read()

        with open(filePath, 'wb') as output:
            output.write(bytearray(content))

    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print e.fp.read()
```

Underneath I test the code by choosing a ticker and time period that I want the stock quotes.

```
from download import constructYFURL, download
from datetime import datetime
from time import time

ticker = "NFLX"

start_date = "2016-07-18"

end_date = "2017-08-18"

freq = "d"

yFURL = constructYFURL(ticker, start_date,end_date,freq)

print yFURL

localFilePath = "/Users/Gebruiker/pytest/nflx.csv"

download(localFilePath,yFURL)
```

This is the resulting url:

https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/NFLX?period1=1468800000&period2=1503014400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=eVjSxKy2scr

The error is given below:

```
{
 "finance": {
    "error": {
        "code": "Unauthorized",
        "description": "Invalid cookie"
    }
  }
}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It does download the file when clicking on the link using my browser, however, is still gives me the error and I cannot find the csv file in the repository I specified for it to be saved. Anyone can help me? I presume by using a handler from the urllib2 python library that handles cookies I can fix this, but I do not know how.

Comment: First, try to fix indentation, please.

Comment: Why not try with ```requests``` library is farly simple use it, it seems be that you dont have auth token, are you sure that pass it in your headers?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to be logged in to have access to that URL.

In this case, you need have cookies in your request's header, and these are generated for you when you log in. It works in your browser because your browser handles it for you.

One way to do it is to use the `requests` module and its [`Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) object, which manages cookies automatically. Create a `Session`, log in from it, and then you should be able to use it to access your URL.

Comment: I think that solves the problem, however, I have no experience with the requests module, could you perhaps write it out how to generate the cookie?

Comment: @JovanGligorević the cookie is generated automatically in the session when you log in through it, no need to worry about it :)

Comment: Sorry I haven't found explanation of 'Session' object in the docs on requests module :( . I use a requests.session() call. What exactly has to be done to authenticate?